# Running AWS ECS Task Attached (Not Detached)

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

Is there easy way to run an [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) Task attached or to follow the logs only while the container is Running (ie. Detach after displaying all of the logs associated)?

Using the AWS CLI (1.17.0) and ecs-cli (1.21.0), I have gotten decently close with the following two commands:

```
aws ecs run-task --cluster "mycluster" --task-definition testhelloworldjob --launch-type FARGATE --network-configuration etc.etc.etc.
        
ecs-cli logs --task-id {TASK_ID_HERE_FROM_OUTPUT_OF_PREVIOUS_COMMAND} --follow
```

I am currently have two issues with the above approach:

1. There is a race condition being that the logs are not available when the task is in a pre "[running](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-lifecycle.html)" state. Instead of `ecs-cli logs` waiting for the logs to exist, there is an error immediately thrown.
2. Even after waiting for the task to be in a running state, and issuing the `ecs-cli logs` the command refuses to detach even AFTER the task is finished and in a Post Running status.

For the first issue I could poll until there is a post activating/pending status, prior to calling logs. For the second issue I could draft some type of threaded call that would poll to stop the following of a log after the container in question is no longer running.... But there has to be an easier way?

To clarify I am coming from numerous other container orchestration tools/technologies that seemingly supported this very seamlessly. Here are some examples of tools and their associated commands that would yield me my intended results:

Docker CLI:

```
docker run hello-world
```

Docker-Compose [Yaml](https://pastebin.com/raw/nyxtYp1t):

```
docker-compose up
```

K8 Kubectl [Yaml](https://pastebin.com/raw/03MgwqWm):

```
kubectl apply -f ./hello-k8.yaml && kubectl logs --follow hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think `ecs-cli` is the best option available at the moment.**

Apart from that, you can change the logs driver of the AWS ECS task to `syslog` and then watch the logs file from the terminal after doing SSH into the EC2 container instance in which it is running.

Another thing you can do is SSH into the EC2 container instance in which it was running before and then run the container of that AWS ECS task by yourself in it using `docker run` and once the testing is done, you can stop and remove that container and then get that task started via AWS ECS.

Note: You can use AWS SSM Session Manager in order to avoid using EC2 key pair and adding an inbound rule for SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way, I also wanted to do this and ended up writing some bash magic to do it.  It is a bit long, but I wrap it in a function that you can just call with a task ID which works for my purposes.  The general idea to solve the above issues is:

1. use `aws ecs wait tasks-running` to block until the log group is created
2. Poll for new log messages in a loop with `--since` until the task is stopped

```bash
# Prints logs like 'tail -f' for an ecs task
function tail_task_logs {
  local TASKID=$1
  local CLUSTER
  local TASK_DEFINITION
  local LGROUP
  CLUSTER=$(echo "$TASKID" | cut -d/ -f1,2 | sed 's/task/cluster/')

  # Lookup the log group name
  TASK_DEFINITION=$(aws ecs describe-tasks \
      --cluster "$CLUSTER" \
      --tasks "$TASKID" \
      --query 'tasks[0].taskDefinitionArn' \
      --output text)
  LGROUP=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition \
      --task-definition "$TASK_DEFINITION" \
      --query 'taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.options."awslogs-group"' \
      --output text)

  # Start tailing once container is running
  SINCE=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
  echo "Waiting for task to start.."
  aws ecs wait tasks-running \
      --cluster "$CLUSTER" \
      --tasks "$TASKID"

  STATUS="None"
  while [[ $STATUS == "None" ]]; do
    # print new messages
    NOW=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    aws logs tail "$LGROUP" --since "$SINCE"
    SINCE="$NOW"
    sleep 2

    # Check if container is still running
    STATUS=$(aws ecs describe-tasks \
        --cluster "$CLUSTER" \
        --tasks "$TASKID" \
        --query 'tasks[0].stopCode' \
        --output text)
  done

  # Print final messages
  aws logs tail "$LGROUP" --since "$SINCE"
  echo "Container exited: $STATUS"
}
```

I tried to make it easy to call, so it does some work to figure the log group which you could remove if you already know it.  You can call it like this

```bash
tail_task_logs "some-task-id"
```

You might be able to simplify using `ecs-cli` but I wanted a version with no extra dependencies.